# Careers: more granular options for distance

Tags: feature-request, jobs, location

When searching for job listings on Stack Overflow Careers, the minimum distance option is 20 miles. This is too far to really do anything to limit the search in London (UK).

It would be nice if the search could be more granular, i.e. 1 mile, 5 miles, 10 miles as options.

Comment: Cross-site dupe of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312585/jobs-distance-dropdown-10-miles-please, which explains that this is impractical because the data simply doesn't have that level of granularity.

Comment: From the linked request, it sounds like the problem is with US zip codes being large. This isn't necessarily a problem for the rest of the world.